# Update binary column values in a dataframe based on checkboxGroupInput in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a long list of checkboxes in a `checkboxGroupInput` statement. The labels and values of the checkboxes correspond to a subset of the `colnames` in a dataframe.

For instance, the dataframe is called `userdf` and has columns like this:

```
A    B    C
1    1    0
```

If the name of the `checkboxGroupInput` is `sotags` then I want `input$sotags` to modify the dataframe such that if it contains `A` but not `B` or `C`:

```
A    B    C
1    0    0
```

My lame attempt at this was:

```
for(i in 1:colnames(userdf)){
   if(colnames(userdf[i]) %in% paste(input$sotags)){userdf[,i] <- 1}
   if(!colnames(userdf[i]) %in% paste(input$sotags)){userdf[,i] <- 0} 
}
```

If you want to see my entire working code, it's here: https://github.com/hack-r/coursera_shiny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say that you start with `userdf` in your code, which in not reactive, like so

`userdf<-data.frame(A=NA,B=NA,C=NA)`

and `input$sotags` is your `checkboxGroupInput` which will be `character` and one of your column names.

Then you can make a new data.frame like so:

```
    userdf2<-reactive({
             as.data.frame(matrix(as.numeric(colnames(userdf)==input$sotags),nrow=1,
                  dimnames=list(NULL,colnames(userdf)))
     })
```

**Edited to Add:**

If `input$sotags` is a character vector, you can replace the `==` with `%in%` in the line starting `as.data.frame` and that will put a 1 in all the selected columns.

Comment: Thank you very much. OK, so when I add this code as you hypothesize I get a colnames error at first: `Error in colnames(userdf2()) <- colnames(userdf) : invalid (NULL) left side of assignment` and then when I click a tab that displays the table (which I'm just doing for testing purposes) it says `Warning in toJSON(unclass(x), container, collapse, ..., .level = .level +  :`. Actually, I have an idea I will try to see if it fixes the error. If you want to test it the code and data are linked in the question. You can clone the repository really fast in RStudio as a project.

Comment: Two updates: you can ignore the `JSON` related warning, I fixed that, it wasn't an error in your code, and also my idea as to how to fix the `colnames` error didn't work

Comment: @Hack-R Just edited to get rid of `colnames` part. Are the column names crucial here? I will try to think of a way to add them.

Comment: @Hack-R I think the `dimnames` bit should fix it. You can add a row name in place of the `NULL` if you like.

Comment: Thanks, I'm testing it out now. The thing is that I have a saved `randomForest` model trained on variables with certain column names. It's actually predicting if you'll get an answer to your Stackoverflow question and `input$sotags` is a list of tags on your post. The name of the tag is the `colnames` in the training dataframe and the rows were binary flags to indicate if the tag was present. So here I'm transforming checkboxes where the user indicates what tags they have into a 1 row dataframe of the same structure as the training dataframe. Make sense?

Comment: Yes, and I am curious what the outcome of the model is! - you should post on Meta if your are happy with it once it is done.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should give the same result as your code:

```
userdf[,input$sotags] <- 1
userdf[,! colnames(userdf) %in% input$sotags] <- 0
```

But that will result in a data frame with all rows being equal... 
Why would you need that?

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try! There's just 1 row. The reason is that I made a predictive algorithm, then I'm letting the user enter their values for the predictors and see which of 2 categories it predicts that they will fall in. Since it's a prediction for just 1 user there's just 1 row.

Comment: I gave you +1 for the help and will leave that there but hmmm it says `Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)`

Comment: Without having the reproducible example, I used the same variables as you did in your attempt, in which the presence of `input$` variables clearly indicated that the presented code belongs to one of the reactive expressions/observers. However, the error indicates that the code from my answer was executed outside of the reactive expressions/observers, so it was obviously misplaced.

Comment: where do I place it? I tried it with and without a reactive expression and got errors both ways. The link to the reproducible example is in the question.